# Fate of the index after truncate partition

Tags: mysql, database-indexes

My question is with regard to understanding the fate of index after a partition is dropped.

After the partition is dropped, what will happen to the index? And again if there is data inserted to the same truncated partition how will the index work?

I understand that there are only locally created indexes in mysql and only the truncated partition's index is affected

Any thoughts on the same will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Indexes will be removed too:

**Important**
Partitioning applies to all data and indexes of a table; you cannot partition only the data and not the indexes, or vice versa, nor can you partition only a portion of the table.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-overview.html